# Many to Many Relationship Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, relationship

```
class Quotation extends Model
{
public function users(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'quotations_users', 'quotation_id', 'user_id');
}

}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
public function quotations(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Quotation', 'quotations_users', 'quotation_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

}

$quotation = Quotation::where('searchable_key', '=', $searchKey)->first();
    $quotation = Quotation::find($quotation->id);
    dd($quotation->users());
```

This code works well but how can I get the name of the user? I used dd($user->users->name) but it didn't work.

Comment: _the_ user? There could be any number of users

Comment: Thanks but I have solved it. I forgot to loop. foreach($quotation->users as $user ){
            dd($user->name);
        }